# Ionic wait GIF end, then change view

Tags: ionic-framework, wait, gif

I have a problem, on my application have to show an animation that they give to me in GIF format when the user clicks a button and change the view after the animation ends.

TS fle:

```
export class AreYouReadyPage {
    private src = 'assets/gif/waiting.gif';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
    }

    noOption() {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }

    yesOption() {
        this.src = 'assets/gif/zucchini-omelet.gif';
        // wait 1 second
        this.navCtrl.push(StepPage, {steps: this.navParams.get('steps')})
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<ion-row>
    <span (click)="yesOption()" class="option-button yes-option">
        <img src="assets/icon/check.png">
    </span>

    <span (click)="noOption()" class="option-button no-option">
        <img src="assets/icon/wrong.png">
    </span>
</ion-row>

<img src="{{src}}" class="celia">

<back-button></back-button>
```

Comment: Beyond trying to keep sync with settimeout, or converting it(them) to something like a sprite image and handling the animation with css, I'd be super interested to hear a solution. +1

Comment: Ooh thank you, I totally forgot the setTimeout, now I'm using it but yes, as you say is not the best solution...

Comment: By the way, I use on Linux an app called Gifsicle to change my gifs and don't let them loop. It has an option to this --no-loopcount